# Layout with layout_marginStart and other attributes not building in MonoDroid, works in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android

I'm attempting to use some layout attributes in MonoDroid and it will not build:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dip" />
```

This builds in Eclipse ADT, but I get this error in visual studio:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
```

The project is set to target Android 4.1, API level 16.

I can use the layout_margin* attributes on non-layout widgets like Button, but they do not build for layout widgets (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc). Again, everything works in Eclipse ADT but fails in visual studio.

Comment: Give it a try with API 17.

Answer (score 0):

This is now building in Mono for Android 4.4.54

Comment: If you answer your own question, you should indicate how you fixed the issue.

Comment: I believe its obvious how the issue was fixed: I upgraded the framework, as stated in the comment.